# I need to select an HTML element when it's clicked using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an HTML file that has list of users on the left side and properties of one user on the right. When I click on some user I can see his properties (name, email, etc), but how can I have user's name selected? My code is

```
.state('user', {
        url: '/user',
        templateUrl: "static/partials/users.html",
        controller: ['$scope', '$http',
            function( $scope,   $http) {

                $scope.users = [];
                $http.get('/api/v1/user/').success(function(data) {
                    $scope.users = data.objects;
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        if(status=401){
                            window.location = '/admin'
                        }
                })
            }
        ]
    })

    .state('user.view', {
        url: '/:userId',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: "static/partials/users.view.html",
                controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams',
                    function( $scope,   $http,   $stateParams) {



                        $scope.selectedUser = {};
                        $http.get('/api/v1/user/'+$stateParams.userId+'/').success(function(data) {
                            $scope.selectedUser = data;
                        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        if(status=401){
                            window.location = '/admin'
                        }
                })
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    })
```

And HTML file is

```
<table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in selectedUser">
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
    </tr>
```

**Update**
Thanks to [TheFox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4957542/thefox) I made it like so:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">

<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="myStyle={color:'red'}">
        <a ui-sref="user.view({userId:user.id})" ng-style="myStyle">{{ user.username }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And nothing more like extra css files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ng-click to add a boolean value or ng-class to dynamically set it up.   Then you can add css to make it look selected.